# Facebook Registration - hidden field does not return data

Tags: php, javascript, xml, facebook

I have set up the facebook registration well, but I have problem with the hidden data. The initial file hae the following fields:

```
{'name':'name'},
{'name':'email'},
{'name':'location', 'description':'Location', 'type':'hidden'},
{'name':'gender', 'description':'Gender', 'type':'hidden'},
{'name':'birthday', 'description':'Birthday', 'type':'hidden'},
....
```

but when a proccess the signed_request I get the hidden field empty as the following:

```
[registration] => Array
 (
   [name] => Juan Perez
   [email] => jual@hotmail.com
   [location] => 
   [gender] => 
   [birthday] => 
   [password] => juan2013
   [phone] => 65656565
   [contacto] => 2
 )
```

Any idea what else need to be set up?

Comment: Have you tried this for more than one users?

Answer (score 0):

The issue may not be to do with your hidden fields. To access the user's location and birthday, additional permissions are required. Make sure you are asking the user for the correct permissions. Also, even with these permissions, the user may not have made this information public.

Comment: if you ask for some permission for accessing some data it should not be public for you to access it.

Comment: What I mean is that the user may not have filled out that particular field on Facebook, or they have changed their privacy settings to stop applications accessing that information.